# How to fix “Failed to Start VirtualBox Linux kernel module” error starting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox

I was attempting to install VirtualBox in Ubuntu. It gave me an error something along the lines of "your kernel is probably out of date". That’s fine, so I go to install 5.15.7 and somehow something went very wrong because now whenever I try to boot into Ubuntu it gives this output. How can I fix this?

[image]

Side note: whenever I try to boot into an older kernel on the advanced boot screen in Ubuntu the screen loads, then immediately selects the first option, aka 5.15.7.

Comment: Are sure it was an error message about the kernel? What usually happens, with Secure Boot enabled in UEFI, is it being unable to the required virtual drivers, namely `vboxdrv`. In such situations the easy solution is disabling Secure Boot, something you can do when dual-booting with Windows 10 but not with Windows 11, modules should be signed by MOK in order to set trust for Secure Boot.

Comment: I tried clearing the secure boot keys in the asus bios and I didn’t seem to have any effect

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot is what should do it for any unsigned drivers like the ones for Nvidia or the virtual drivers for Virtualbox. Or use MOK, that is.

Comment: Did I not disable secure boot?

Comment: How should I know? I'm not seeing what you're seeing. Enabling/disabling is an ON/OFF switch so if you think clearing keys disables it then no, it doesn't.

Comment: If clearing the keys doesn't disable secure boot, what does? Every article/guide I can find says to clear keys.

Comment: In your firmware you should find a settings to enable/disable Secure Boot. Each one is different therefore it's not possible to tell you exactly where it can be found but please check your user's manual or online resources.